# How to intercept the HTTPs traffic with BurpSuite (or any other proxy tools) for iOS mobile applications

Tags: ios, security, testing, penetration-testing, flutter-ios

Due to in-built feature of flutter, it is not possible to intercept the `HTTPs` traffic with `BurpSuite` via a traditional way `(an SSL-Pinning bypass does not work with Objection)`. Since it is proxy-unaware, I am struggling to capture the `HTTPs` traffic for penetration testing (mostly dynamic analysis). I have come across one workaround by routing the mobile traffic via `OpenVPN` but that option does not work for me. Would like to know if there are any working solutions that can resolve this traffic interception issue, particularly for `iOS` mobile apps from a tester point of view?